# Camel AWS SNS - Invalid parameter: TopicArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel

I'm trying to send messages to an AWS SNS topic using AWS Camel.
I've defined the SNS Client as follows:

```
<bean name="snsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
            <constructor-arg value="${access.key}"/>
            <constructor-arg value="${secret.key}"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And the following Camel route:

```
<route id="content.publication.receipting.CPS">
...
  <to id="DeliverBundleToPIPS" uri="aws-sns://arn:aws:sns:<MyRegion>:<MyAccount>:<MySNSTopicArn>?amazonSNSClient=#snsClient"></to>
</route>
```

It fails with the following message:

```
WARN  Exchange failed, so rolling back message status: Exchange[ID-U6023035-TPL-A-64492-1498559205318-0-2]
com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 7a352f55-22f0-59c4-9c68-7e9917bdec0f)
```

,  and  are correct values.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and tests I got it work by explicitly specifying the amazonSNSEndpoint:

```
<route id="content.publication.receipting.CPS">
...
  <to id="DeliverBundleToPIPS" uri="aws-sns://arn:aws:sns:<MyRegion>:<MyAccount>:<MySNSTopicArn>?amazonSNSClient=#snsClient&amp;amazonSNSEndpoint=sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"></to>
</route>
```

It looks like the default region selection mechanism does not work fine in this case.